# Most efficient way to create multi line HTML in jQuery

Tags: jquery

So I've been looking around and it would appear that `$(document.createElement(name));` might be the most efficient way in jQuery to create HTML.

However if I were trying to write lines of HTML is this neccisarily the best method? Can you write multiple lines using this method?

For instance, my desired output is:

```
<div id="measurements">
  <span>Width:</span><p id="width"></p>
  <span>Height:</span><p id="height"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I would go with `$("<div />", { id : "measurements" }).append( ... )`

Comment: Why would `$(document.createElement(name))` be the most efficient? And are you looking to add that whole block of HTML to the DOM, inside another element, or just part of it?

Comment: The reason I said that was due to some other answers I'd seen, hence why I wanted to check. I'm just looking to add a block of HTML inside the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you feel wrapping `createElement()` is the "most efficient" - in that case, I'd almost surely say:

```
$(name)
```

In the latter case, you can just wrap all that up in one `$()` call:

```
var mydiv = '<div id="measurements">' +
  '<span>Width:</span><p id="width"></p>' +
  '<span>Height:</span><p id="height"></p>' +
  '</div>';
```